# Python: How can I add the line number of frequencies and sort alphabetically using dictionaries

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a project where I must obtain the amount of frequencies of each word through sys.stdin

I have obtained that part. The second part is getting the line number for each word, I feel I have obtained that but I cannot add to the output string the line number and I also cant figure out a way to sort alphabetically if the word has the same frequency

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

wordCount = defaultdict(list)
words = {}

for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin.readlines()):
    wordCount[line].append(i+1) #add the line number to each element in the line
    for word in line.lower().split():
        words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

sortedList = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for word, frequency in sortedList:
    print("%d %s" % (frequency, word))," " # <-- HERE I NEED TO ADD THE LINE NUMBER AND ALSO SORT ALPHABETICALLY
```

If I input "Python is really cool" #line 1
"I am working with python really" #line 2

Output should be:

```
2 python 1 2

2 really 1 2

1 am 2

1 cool 1

1 I 2

1 is 1

1 with 2

1 working 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know about defaultdict, I would continue with that -- Although I would use a `defaultdict(list)` which had `words` as keys and the values would a list of the line numbers.  Then, at the end, you can just iterate through your dictionary getting the `len` of the list to get your count (possibly using a `sorted` `set` when you print the line numbers to get rid of duplicates).